# IIS web site can't connect SQL Server, but the server that hosts IIS can

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, iis, silverlight

Here is the architecture :

- One server A with a SQL 2014 database
- One other server B with IIS hosting Silverlight apps

From server B, I can ping server A, and I can connect SQL using a small testing program.

The problem is : The web sites on server B can't connect SQL on A.

Very strange, considering that all connection strings used are the same, and with a specified SQL user (not integrated security) :

```
data source=ServerA;initial catalog=TestDB;user id=userid;password=password;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework
```

Moreover, the exact same sites used to work on another IIS server.

I wish I could provide you some error information, but I can't have it... It's like the data loading and connection fail silently despite my efforts to bring errors to the surface. All I can see is that my data doesn't load (empty grids in the interface)

What can be the cause of such behavior ?

Comment: If you can connect from a "small testing program" which I assume is something that you run from a command line and cannot from a website most likely it's a driver issue...

Comment: the testing program uses System.data.SqlClient SqlConnection while the website uses EntityFramework. Do you have a specific driver in mind ?

Comment: Downvoter, I'm all ears to know what is wrong with my question and improve myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I had this working.
There was 2 steps :

- Enable the 'HTTP Activation' role on the IIS server
- Local copy = True on all the server project references

Thanks all